# Get uploaded attachment by attachment id - Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I try to send a message with attachment id but the attachment doesn't show up, so I want to check it's existed or not. Is there any facebook api to do that?

More detail:
I created a qr image by google chart url like this

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=QRCODE
```

Then upload it to facebook and store attachment id on my database to reuse. I still got an attachment id after uploading but when send it to facebook messenger it doesn't show up.
I think the problem is that facebook doesn't recognize the above url is an image url.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to do this is to send a message with the attachment_id. I think the issues may be that you are pointing to a dynamically generated image. The Attachment Upload API needs to be pointed to an actual file, though it is strange you are still receiving an attachment ID. One other thing to note is that attachment ID is not supported in any of the template.

Answer (score 0):

I just double checked my codes, the problem is wrong recipient id not the image url. Sorry for the wrong question.